# How to show this function is convex? is there any simpler way than Hessian computation?

Tags: linear-algebra, convex-analysis, numerical-linear-algebra

i need to show $f(x)=-\log{\frac{exp(C_{\{k,:\}}x)}{\sum_j exp(C_{\{j,:\}}x)}}$ is convex. $x \in R^n$ and $exp(v)$ is the element-wise exponential of $v$ and $C \in  R^{d \times n}$. Notation $C_{\{k,:\}}$ means the $i$th row of $C$.

In fact it is the intersection of 3 functions, $\{-log(p),\frac{exp(p_k)}{\sum_j exp(p_j)}, Cx\}$. I tried to calculate Hessian, but i obtained a complicated matrix with too many terms to show it is PSD.

I know it is PSD because i used matlab Hessian approximation and tried that with all kinds of $x$ and the result was PSD.

Besides proving Hessian being PSD, is there any other way easier to prove its convexity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you're asking how to show the function $f(x) = -\log\left(\frac{e^{\theta_i^T x} }{\sum_{j=1}^N e^{\theta_j^T x}} \right)$ is convex in $x\in \mathbf{R}^n$? If so, you can easily rewrite this as

$$f(x) = -\theta_i^T x - \log\left(\sum_{j=1}^N e^{\theta_j^T x}\right)$$

The first term is obviously convex in $x$ (specifically linear), and the second term is the negation of the *log-sum-exp* function. I think what you meant to say about the intersection above, is that this function is actually the *composition* of three functions.

There are some conditions (section 3.2.4 of [Boyd](https://web.stanford.edu/~boyd/cvxbook/bv_cvxbook.pdf)) under which compositions of functions are sufficient to yield convex/concave functions but the log-sum-exp is a standard example of a function that cannot be proved concave by these rules (they are sufficient, not necessary).

You can compute the Hessian of this and use the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality to prove concavity. The negation is then obviously convex. See page 74 of [Stephen Boyd's](https://web.stanford.edu/~boyd/cvxbook/bv_cvxbook.pdf) book on convex optimization

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you mean by "intersection of 3 functions". I also don't know if your $f$ is a function since you talk about element-wise exponentials.

The class of convex functions is closed under addition, multiplication by nonnegative scalars, and taking the supremum, having first an affine function etc.

As a first step, I would simplify using properties of the log. Next, there is a term appeared of the form log-sum-exp (from the denominator). This function is known to be convex (and yes, the cheapest proof is through the Hessian). Together with some calculus rules, this should give your convexity.